# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, cmd, build, apk

**{ Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Vivek Sharma\apps\testAp
p\www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db’**

**errno: -4048,

code: ‘EPERM’,

syscall: ‘open’,**

path: ‘C:\Users\Vivek Sharma\apps\testApp\www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db’ }

[03:09:32] deeplinks started …

[03:09:32] deeplinks finished in 110 ms

[03:09:32] ngc started …

[03:09:59] ngc finished in 26.71 s

[03:09:59] preprocess started …

[03:09:59] preprocess finished in 3 ms

[03:09:59] webpack started …

[03:11:33] webpack finished in 94.64 s

[03:11:33] uglify started …

[03:11:33] sass started …

**Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open ‘C:\Users\Vivek Sharma\apps\testApp
www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db’**

(node:14288) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled async
hronously (rejection id: 1)

[03:11:36] sass finished in 2.99 s

[03:11:36] cleancss started …

[03:11:40] cleancss finished in 3.62 s

[03:12:08] uglify finished in 34.76 s

---------------------END-----------------------------------

This error occurs when trying to build apk. using **ionic cordova build android --release --prod** in windows cmd

ionic v-3.19.0
cordova -v-8.0.0
node -v-8.8.3
npm -v-5.3.0

WINDOWS 8.1 64 bit.

full control is given to the system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hufNl.jpg)

please help

Comment: Please, can you add some details about your intentions? What do you want to do? what commands are runned? etc. . Thanks

Comment: This error occurs when trying to build apk. using the following command:-

 ionic cordova build android --release --prod

 in windows cmd

Comment: @viveksharma are u importing SQLite DB from the below mentioned location C:\Users\Vivek Sharma\apps\testAp p\www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db’

Comment: No. I am not, @Nidhinkumar

Comment: @viveksharma have you tried the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, Developers, for responding to my query. I have resolved the issue. The problem was, Windows keeps building Thumbnails and stores them as Thumbs.db on the system.This prevents the system from copying, moving, deleting or renaming a folder. I prevented further caching of thumbnails and deleted the Thumbs.db from the project folder.

This is the procedure if anyone else comes across this problem:

**1. Disabling Thumbs.db:**

https://www.nextofwindows.com/what-is-thumbs-db-files-and-how-to-disable-and-remove-them

**2. Next, to remove Thumbs.db:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7MgnYCMvHE

This will do the job. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your folder name has a white space try to rename the folder name and try to run it again.

Existing Path:

```
C:\Users\Vivek Sharma\apps\testAp p\www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db
```

Change Path like this:

```
C:\Users\VivekSharma\apps\testApp\www\assets\imgs\Thumbs.db
```

You could see whitespace in between Vivek Sharma change it to VivekSharma   For more info check this out:
  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted/92788)